# How to make cxf consumer wait indefenity till it get response from JMS

Tags: jms, cxf, apache-servicemix

Design: The servicemix cxf consumer target service is jms and the jms target service is cxf provider.

Problem: The consumer doesn't wait till the response is received from provider even though http-conduit is implemented for consumer and provider.
Once jms is removed and if provider is made as target for consumer , the consumer waits indefinitely .

Kindly suggest the configurations required to make the consumer wait even with JMS

Comment: What version of servicemix do you use?

Comment: The whole point of JMS is to make things happen asynchronously. Don't use JMS at all if you want synchronous requests. Or if you want to redirect your request depending on some parameters either it has to be JMS or not, use Apache Camel to route the request to the different transport.

Comment: @Claus ServiceMix version 3.4